Exception thrown at 0x00007FF80D67FE4C and I don't know how to find the problem
I'm building an application that uploads files to Google Drive. On debug, the app goes well, with all the exceptions.
I tried to move it to Release Mode, but the application crashed when starting. I enabled Native Code Debugging (Mixed-Mode) to find the problem, and I got an error on IAppWindowMethods Class.
the error was on set_IsShownInSwitchers()->
    public unsafe static void set_IsShownInSwitchers(IObjectReference _obj, bool value)
    {
        IntPtr thisPtr = _obj.ThisPtr;
        ExceptionHelpers.ThrowExceptionForHR(((delegate* unmanaged[Stdcall]<IntPtr, byte, int>)(*(IntPtr*)((nint)(*(IntPtr*)(void*)thisPtr) + (nint)8 * (nint)sizeof(delegate* unmanaged[Stdcall]<IntPtr, byte, int>))))(thisPtr, value ? ((byte)1) : ((byte)0)));
    }

On the ExceptionHelpers, there was this error
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF80D67FE4C (KernelBase.dll) in ACloud.exe: 0x8001010D: An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call.
I've looked a lot and didn't find something that stopped the problem.
There are a lot of classes and files and I can't copy all the files to a new project to find the problem by adding files every time.
Can someone explain what this error is and how should I fix it?
Sorry about my English.

View the 'Call stack' to find where IN YOUR CODE it goes wrong.

@PoulBak I tried. It shows a lot of letters there
rpcrt4.dll! and more letters

You might need to clear the exceptions you are seeing in Debug.

@AndrewKeepCoding The exceptions are only on Release Mode and Mixed-Mode Debug. I don't understand those exceptions.

So you mean "On debug, the app goes well, without all the exceptions." right? Then can you add a simple logging to track what exactly is crashing the app?

@AndrewKeepCoding i noticed that even creating a new winui progect and enable mixed debug and all exceptions, it still throwing some exceptions. that is the same exceptions that I have. the problem is that it stopping my app
